# Good tutorial on using Quads for custom Text in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, bitmap, textures

I'm currently new to OpenGL ES and am self teaching myself how to program iOS games. I'm currently playing with a project that I would like to put a HUD over with some custom text. I don't want to do this using a UILabel and currently have no idea how to use Quads to cut up a png or such full of text and attach them to normal text to be used for display. I would like the end result to be providing a simple string to a command/method and the output to be displayed using the textures/bitmap for the quad. Say glPrint("Hello World");. Would anyone be able to guide me in the proper direction? There doesn't seem to be a single good tutorial on how to do this for OpenGL ES 2.0 (just OpenGL). I also want to try to avoid using 3rd party APIs. I really need/want to understand how to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was getting started with OpenGL ES for my current 2D project I used [Ray's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1), which helped me get a handle on rendering textured 2D quads. In conjunction with his [3D OpenGL ES tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5235/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-2), you might be able to piece together what you want to do. Note that you probably wouldn't render every single quad separately like in the tutorial, as that is very inefficient. Instead, you would gather all of the vertices of the characters into two big arrays/vertex buffers and batch render the characters. The basic flow for rendering each frame would probably look like this: pass a normal perspective projection matrix for 3D rendering, get your vertex information for your 3D scene to your shaders somehow, render the 3D scene. This part you've already done. For the text, immediately after, pass an orthogonal projection matrix in, bind your font texture (generally generated earlier with the `GLKTextureLoader` class) to the active texture unit, generate two big arrays of texture and geometric vertices for the characters/update VBOs if the text has changed, pass that in, and then batch render all of the letters at once using either `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` (which requires indices).

Also, as I'm also new at using OpenGL, some of this may be wrong/inefficient. I've yet to use OpenGL ES to render anything 3D, so I'm not sure what other state changes (enabling, disabling, etc) besides a different projection matrix might be needed between rendering your 3D scene and the 2D scene (text).

It seems that drawing text using only OpenGL is a relatively difficult and tedious task, so if you just want to render a HUD overlay displaying frame rates and other things you are much better off using `UILabel`s and saving yourself the trouble, especially if your project is not very complex. This also prevents you from having to deal with wrapping, kerning, font sizes, colors, different languages and a load of other stuff that greatly complicates text rendering if you need anything more complex.

Comment: Ah, thank for the answer. I'm honestly looking for a bit more in depth and was looking into those specific tutorials. My main problem is wrapping my head around how to tie specific letters to the quads. I've never done anything like that before. Say I make a function that prints quads with the associated textures for letters. The function name is glPrintf(); and takes a string as an argument. If I pass in glPrintf("Hello World"); how am I going to identify the location of every letter (h, e, l, l, o, etc) to a quad position and print it out. That's where my main ideal problem lies.

Comment: I mean, must I convert the chars to their ASKII values and do a calculation from there in relation to the coordinates in the quad? More of less, that's what I'm having the hardest time understanding.

Comment: For simple text, I would recommend a texture with all the characters in the ASCII character set (where Non-printable characters are empty squares) in the order they appear in, in said set. Then, examine the ASCII value of each character in the string. Since it matches with your texture, you know the letter number. Now you need the (zero-based) row and column of the letter in your texture. The row would be `floor(letterIndex / charactersPerRowInTexture)` and the column would be `letterIndex % charactersPerRowInTexture`. From there, figure out the x/y stride between two characters and multiply.

Comment: That sounds pretty right to me. I guess I just have to tackle it first XD. Thank you for reassuring me on that. Still would love a good tutorial though.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than tracking the location of each letter, why not use Core Graphics to draw your entire string into a bitmap, then upload that as a texture? You'd just need to get the dimensions from your bitmap to know what size quad to draw for that text string.

Within my open source GPUImage framework, I have an input class called a GPUImageUIElement that does something similar. The relevant code from that input is as follows:

```
CGSize layerPixelSize = [self layerSizeInPixels];

GLubyte *imageData = (GLubyte *) calloc(1, (int)layerPixelSize.width * (int)layerPixelSize.height * 4);

CGColorSpaceRef genericRGBColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();    
CGContextRef imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, (int)layerPixelSize.width, (int)layerPixelSize.height, 8, (int)layerPixelSize.width * 4, genericRGBColorspace,  kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, 0.0f, layerPixelSize.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(imageContext, layer.contentsScale, -layer.contentsScale);

[layer renderInContext:imageContext];

CGContextRelease(imageContext);
CGColorSpaceRelease(genericRGBColorspace);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)layerPixelSize.width, (int)layerPixelSize.height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

free(imageData);
```

This code takes a CALayer (either directly or from the backing layer of a UIView) and renders its contents to a texture. I've already initialized the texture before this, so the code sets up a bitmap context, renders the layer into that context using `-renderInContext:`, and then uploads that bitmap to the texture for use in OpenGL ES.

The helper method `-layerSizeInPixels` just accounts for the current Retina scale factor as follows:

```
- (CGSize)layerSizeInPixels;
{
    CGSize pointSize = layer.bounds.size;
    return CGSizeMake(layer.contentsScale * pointSize.width, layer.contentsScale * pointSize.height);
}
```

If you used a UILabel for your view and had it autosize to fit its text, you could set the text on it, use the above to render and upload your texture, and then take the pixel size of the element to determine your quad size. However, it would probably be more efficient to just draw the text yourself using `-drawAtPoint:withFont:fontForSize:` or the like with an NSString.

Using Core Graphics to render your text makes it easy to manipulate the text as an NSString and use all of Core Graphics' typesetting capabilities instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if the answer above quite provides what I'm looking for. I'm not looking to rip an already typed out font from the system into a texture. I'm more so interested in creating my own custom fonts and rendering those as textures. (like a sprite sheet with custom drawn text that I may match up to a string on the fly). I also noticed the declaration of `glTexImage2D` in the above code... which doesn't exist in OpenGL ES 2.0. I ran into that issue earlier when trying to reference Mac code for iOS code.

Comment: @TheGamingArt - The above code is copied and pasted from here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage which is my iOS OpenGL ES 2.0 framework, so `glTexImage2D()` most definitely does exist in OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't think the answer above is what I was looking for.. but I could have sworn I tried an OpenGL ES call to something called with a 2D Tex Image in the call and found it wasn't supported in 2.0. I'll have to double back into that then.